# Зачем нужен отдельный объект для блокировки?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть код

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<int> nums;
    private object _syncRoot = new object();

    public void Add1(int item)
    {
         lock(_syncRoot)
         {
            nums.Add(item);
         }
    }

    public void Add2(int item)
    {
         lock(nums){
            nums.Add(item);
         }
    }
}
```

Почему правильно `Add1` а не `Add2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В рамках вашего примера, формально оба варианта равноценны (лишь бы они не применялись одновременно). Вариант с отдельным приватным объектом является более идиоматичным, т. к. формально говоря, нет гарантии что кто-то ещё каким-то необычным образом не лочит `List<int>` (например, конструктор самого `List<int>`).

Разница будет в случае, когда `nums` может «утечь» наружу (например, вы выдаёте его через какой-то метод). В этом случае внешний код может для своих внутренних целей сделать `lock(nums)`, и под ним ожидать окончания операции, выполняющейся в другом потоке. Если эта операция попытается вызвать `Add2`, вы получите deadlock.

К сожалению, это не такой уж и невероятный вариант развития событий.

Например, часто применяется форма `lock(this)`, в которой объект, по которому ведётся блокировка, очевидно доступен снаружи, и таким образом, любой код может (случайно) организовать deadlock.

Для случая приватного объекта, который нужен лишь для блокировки, не возникает соблазна вынести его наружу. Ну и семантически правильнее, когда каждый объект выполняет лишь одну функцию.

Поэтому пользуйтесь вариантом с отдельным объектом для блокировки. Так вы ограждаете себя от потенциальных ошибок и необходимости думать о том, можете ли вы сделать именно этот объект публичным.

---

Официальная майкрософтовская [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) говорит:

> В общем случае избегайте блокировок по публичному типу, или по объектам, не находящихся под полным вашем контролем. Распространённые конструкции наподобие `lock (this)`, `lock (typeof (MyType))`, или `lock ("myLock")` нарушают этот принцип:
>
> - `lock (this)` может привести к проблемам, если этот экземпляр может быть доступен внешнему коду.
> - `lock (typeof (MyType))` может привести к проблемам, если тип `MyType` объявлен как `public`.
> - `lock("myLock")` может привести к проблемам, потому что любой код в пределах вашего *процесса*, использующий ту же строку, получит ту же блокировку.
>
> Лучше всего объявите приватный объект специально для блокировки по нему. Если вам нужно защитить данные, общие для всех объектов данного класса, используйте приватный статический объект.